# Angular, ngx-charts. Print in firefox

Tags: angular, firefox, printing, ngx-charts

If the page using @media print will be printed in Firefox, ngx-charts's bars are losing their colours. In Google Chrome I can get a page that has been printed right.

Examples:

Google Chrome
[image: GC'S print]

Firefox

[image: Ff's print]

The pictures are screenshots of print reviews in each browser, but if I save it as pdf, I still have the same issue.

I think it's something about ngx-charts. Has somebody any idea, why there is the issue and how could it be fixed?

Comment: can you give a stackblitz?

Comment: @AakashGarg I'm not actually sure. At first, there are too many files and it can be difficult to navigate. And I don't think that I'm allowed. I could add css and HTML files of the component. Would that enough?

Comment: create a normal ngx-chart with normal media print css? not all your data?

Comment: @AakashGarg that sounds like a compromise. Give me some time.

Comment: you have which version of firefox?

Comment: @AakashGarg I've done that on stackblitz and there wasn't the issue. There is the  [link.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-charts-avucsi) 

Firefox's version is 77.0 (64-Bit)

Comment: then can't tell, until its reproduced.

Comment: @AakashGarg Thank you a lot. At least I have a little bit of information about the bug.